# Extract TIFF from PDF with PDFBox v2

Tags: java, pdfbox, tiff

It was possible to extract images including TIFF format using PDFBox v1.x. It is still possible to extract some formats with version 2.0.1 but it seems not to be working for TIFF format.

```
for (COSName c : page.getResources().getXObjectNames()) {
    PDXObject o = resources.getXObject(c);
    if (o instanceof PDImageXObject) {
        PDImageXObject image = (PDImageXObject) o;
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            ImageIO.write(image.getImage(), image.getSuffix(), bout);
            System.out.println("Image Bytes: " + bout.size());
        }
    }
}
```

ByteArrayOutputStream in above code has bytes for PNG and JPEG but nothing for TIFF. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is the question: Does ImageIO support TIFF? Try replacing  image.getSuffix() with "png" so it attempts to save it as a png. If it does work then, your ImageIO just doesnt support writing TIFF files.

Comment: "but it seems not to be working" is not very specific. `image.getSuffix()` returns "tiff" when the image is encoded in a ccitt format in the pdf file. You did not link to a specific PDF file. And `ImageIO.write()` will work properly only if jai_imageio.jar is in your classpath. 1: check the return value of `ImageIO.write()`. 2: use `ImageIOUtils`, this will check that the lib is there. 3: read the dependencies: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html 4: use the latest version, which is 2.0.2. (only since yesterday :-))

Comment: I have tried version 2.0.2 but result was same. JAI's imageio, codec and core are in classpath and 'ImageIOUtils.writeImage' produced result similar to 'ImageIO.write'. But treating TIFF as a PNG (as suggested by @user254948) worked, i.e. I was able to save TIFF as PNG, edit it and save it back in PDF. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

To extract PDF to the TIFF format, you need to include the *jai_imageio* library in the classpath.

I used the distribution from the geotoolkit repository, here is my pom.xml extract:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Geotoolkit</id>
        <name>Geotoolkit</name>
        <url>http://maven.geotoolkit.org/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--required by PDFBox to create tiff images-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai_imageio</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```